# URL troca mas view mantém - routing com angular 4

Tags: angular

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou criando uma página no angular onde ela irá ter um botão que irá passar como parametro um ID e receber este ID na outra página. Estou usando o Router do angular mas não estou conseguindo. Fiz com que a URL mudasse, mas a view ainda mantém da página anterior.

```
<td><button [routerLink]="['/editar', cliente.id]">Alterar</button></td>
```

No meu botão, estou utilizando o código acima para trocar a página.

meu app.module está assim:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'listar', component: ClienteListarPage },
{ path: 'inserir', component: ClienteInserirEditarPage },
{ path: 'editar/:id', component: ClienteInserirEditarPage }
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ClienteListarPage,
        ClienteInserirEditarPage
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ClienteService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

e a página que irá abrir está assim:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './inserir-editar.html'
})
export class ClienteInserirEditarPage implements OnInit {
    id: number;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
}
```

O console.log que está dentro da class ClienteInserirEditarPage não está sendo executado. Tentei utilizar este método de navegação também:

```
this.router.navigate(['/editar', id]);
```

Mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Verifique se a tag `<router-outlet>` está inserida no app.html e se não possui nenhum filtro de nome: `<router-outlet name="list">`

Comment: Bom dia amigo, tente executar assim ngOnInit() { let teste = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); console.log(teste ); }

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema... conseguiu resolver?